# Problems with guessing game Java

Tags: java

I am having a little trouble figuring out what is going on in my code (Go figure...)
Some of my final int values I have not touched on yet, but I will after I can get some of these other issues sorted out.

1. I cannot figure out why after changing correctGuess to true I cannot receive more input from my user before the program exits to decide if they'd like to keep playing.
2. This is supposed to take the milliseconds from someone's computer and gather a random number between 1-110, but sometimes I get negative numbers and cannot seem to figure out what the issue is with that.

Any help would be appreciated...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessingGame {
    private static final int MIN_NUMBER = 1;
    private static final int MAX_NUMBER = 110;
    private static final int EXIT_VALUE = -1;
    private static final int MAX_GAMES = 256;


    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        System.out.println("*** You are playing the CSC110 Guessing Game ***");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int totalGames = 0;
        int wonGames = 0;
        int guess = 0;

        boolean playing = true;

        while (playing) {
            boolean correctGuess = false;
            totalGames++;

            Random rg = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
            int n = MIN_NUMBER + rg.nextInt() % (MAX_NUMBER - MIN_NUMBER);


            System.out.println("Pick a number between 1 and 110 (-1 to exit): ");

            int numberOfTries = 0;

            while (!correctGuess)
            {
                guess = scanner.nextInt();
                numberOfTries++;
                System.out.print(numberOfTries);

                if (guess == n) {
                    System.out.print("Congrats, it took you " + numberOfTries + " try/tries to get the right number!");
                    System.out.print("Do you want to play again? (Yes/No)");
                    correctGuess = true;
                }
                else if(guess != n && numberOfTries < 5)
                {
                    System.out.println("nope... \n");
                }

                else if(guess > n && numberOfTries >= 5)
                {
                    System.out.print("Try something lower \n");
                }
                else if(guess < n && numberOfTries >= 5)
                {
                    System.out.print("Try something higher \n");
                }
            }
            String playAgain = scanner.nextLine();
            if(playAgain.equals("Yes"))
            {
                playing = true;
            }
            else
            {
                playing = false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `scanner.nextLine()` just before `String playAgain = scanner.nextLine();`

Comment: Add this to generate your random number `int n = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 110 + 1);` First param is inclusive, second is exclusive, thats why you add the + 1

Answer (score 1):

1: Tested with the following and it worked properly:

```
String playAgain = scanner.next();
```

You might also consider revising your if statement as follows:

```
if(playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes") || playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
```

2: The simplest way to make sure the number comes out positive would be using Math.abs().

```
int n = Math.abs(MIN_NUMBER + rg.nextInt() % (MAX_NUMBER - MIN_NUMBER));
```